# Import ASCII table in C as array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a series of data saved as a table in an ASCII file, for example:

```
1   100  2.345
2   342  8.233
3   65   89.23
```

I have just returned back to **C** after a few years of working in Python and wondered isn't there already any library that can do this import? Something like `numpy.loadtxt()` in Python? For example to output a float or a double array? I remember in the past I had to write a program myself to do this job in **C** (C99 for example), is there any standard package that will do the import? How about saving the results to an ASCII file? I can write a program myself for both of these but I don't want to repeat what other people have definitely done before me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own library to do this (with the help of the kind people here who answered my questions very promptly), you can see it [here](https://github.com/makhlaghi/attaavv). It does the job of turning a table of data (with an unknown number of headers, columns and rows) to a C array that can be used in the program. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For machine generated files with a regular format, `fscanf()` can work flawlessly:

```
int index;
int x;
double y;

while (fscanf(infile, "%d %d %lf\n", &index, &x, &y) == 3) {
    /* ... */
}
```

If you want to be able to handle files with any number of columns and just have the files fed into a data structure that you can later search or manipulate, then it is probably better to use a program or script to generate the same table in CSV or XML format. Then, use a library like [`libcsv`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/) or [Mini-XML](http://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z3) to parse the file for you.

Comment: Thanks, Isn't there a more general method so for example the number of columns in the data doesn't have to be known before hand? Or in a case where the table has for example 50 columns! It is impractical to designate all the column formats by hand and define variables based on each specific table!

Comment: Your best bet to achieve what you want is to write a program that will convert arbitrary text tables into CSV or XML format, and use existing libraries that will generate data structures based on those inputs for you.

Comment: Can you please introduce me to some of those "existing libraries"?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and introduction of the two packages, I understood what you mean.